# how to fastly find array which include some numbers(1~255)?

Tags: algorithm, passwords, find

I want to solve some algorithm problem.
Could you suggest any algorithms working more fast?

*Problem summary
- Find same array of key[200] is same as source array KEY[200]
- Each element of KEY[200] array is random numbers range 1~255
- only 2 file are given.
- You must implement just function find_array() of user_code.cpp
- It is not allowed to edit any other things
- You can use check() function for finding array
- test case is 50, time limit is 10 sec for 50 test case, memory limit is 256MB.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

extern void find_array(unsigned char key[200]);

unsigned char KEY[200];

int check(unsigned char key[200])
{
    int pos = 0;
    int equal = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < 200; c++)
    {
        if (key[c] == KEY[c])
            pos++;
    }

    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < 200; c1++)
    {
        for (int c2 = 0; c2 < 200; c2++)
        {
            if(key[c1] == KEY[c2])
                equal++;
        }
    }

    return pos * 256 + equal;
}


int main()
{
    for (int t = 0; t < 1; t++) //test case 50개
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            KEY[i] = rand() % 255 + 1;  //1~255
        }

        unsigned char key[200] = { 0, };
        find_array(key); //you must implement this function                     
    }

    return 0;
}




//user_code.cpp
extern int check(unsigned char key[200]);


//you must implement this function
//below is my code take a long time(about 2sec for each case)
void find_array(unsigned char key[200])
{
    unsigned char temp[200];
    int result, pos, equal;

    for (int k = 0; k < 200; k++)
        temp[k] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        for (int val = 1; val <= 255; val++)
        {
            temp[i] = val;

            result = check(temp);
            equal = result % 256;
            pos = (result - equal) / 256;

            if (pos >= 1)
            {
                key[i] = val;
                temp[i] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is not clear

Comment: Would calculating a hash value for each array help?

Comment: I want to find all values in array that made by rand(). I can edit only find_array() function. I can not edit oher codes.

Comment: You will need to explain more... But I can tell you now that your code is `O(n^4)` (since you use `check()` which is `O(n^2)` in a double loop), for a problem that sounds like it can be solved in `O(n^2)`, if not `O(n)` using hashmap.

Comment: In order to help us, please *show* and *explain* an input and output example.

Comment: Thank you reply. There is no input , output files. Because test input is generated by rand() function for every test case. And result is just elapsed time. How to make hash map from array filled with random number? User can't know any information about the KEY[] array except check() function. But user find KEY[] array fast. Thanks in advance.